# How do I handle the new isCustomElement setup for using web components in Vue 3 when unit testing with Jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, web-component, vuejs3

I am trying to write unit tests for my Vue 3 app using web components.
I have Jest configured containing transform options:

```
  // ...
  "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  // ...
```

I need to use isCustomElement which is now required at compilation time, so I’ve added options based on the proposed solution in Vue3 docs like I did in webpack. I played around with it in the transform and global options. And also tried adding it to my babel.config.

```
  // ...
  "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$":  ["vue-jest", {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: tag => tag === 'my-custom-component'
        }
      }],
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  // ...
```

However it’s still throwing a Vue warn when running tests:
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: my-custom-component.

Any ideas how to make isCustomElement work with Jest? I am at a loss as to what I need to set up to get rid of the console warnings and properly render the web components. In Vue 2 I just had to add them to setupFiles directly.

Comment: After more searching I tried using jest-electron:

` runner: 'jest-electron/runner', 
  testEnvironment: 'jest-electron/environment',
`

I got rid of the console warnings about unknown elements with this. However, looking at the snapshot the custom elements are still not rendering like they used to in my old setup in Vue 2.

Comment: Are you trying to test the component, or you're testing something else? If you're testing something else you could stub your custom element:

mount(Component, {
  stubs: ['registered-component']
})

Comment: I am testing the vue component using some web components if the form of buttons etc. I could indeed stub them like that, or maybe even create some global stub for all of them, but I used to be able to get them rendered from Jest by just adding them to setupFiles in the Jest config. So I figured that although Vue 3 changed when web components are compiled, I would still be able to somehow get that back.

Comment: Yeah if you want it to be rendered you could either try to create a wrapper component or something like this https://matthias-kainer.de/blog/posts/testing-webcomponents-with-jest-and-dom-testing-tools/

Comment: Stuck on this as well. Have tried Vue Test Utils' `options.global.config` (https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global), which looked like a home run, but no luck.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this as well...